# Where does "ipsec import" store certificate file?

Tags: import, certificate, ipsec, p12, libreswan

I'm now setting up libreswan server - client.
Basically, I'm trying to follow a procedure described here.
https://kifarunix.com/setup-ipsec-vpn-server-with-libreswan-on-centos-8/

I created client certificate which is aaa.bbb.p12 from the server machine using pk12util command.
And copied to client machine and import using ipsec import aaa.bbb.p12

ipsec import aaa.bbb.p12 was successful.
But I don't know where this file stored when ipsec import command was executed.
Is there any way I can browse this certificate file using a certain command?

Answer (score 0):

I found something but not perfect.
I copied aaa.bbb.p12 and used ipsec command like below.

```
# ipsec import ./aaa.bbb.p12 --nssdir /etc/ipsec.d/certsdb
```

Then, I can see the certificate using the command below.

```
# certutil -L -d sql:/etc/ipsec.d/certsdb
```

But I still have one more problem.
If I import one more certificate file such as aaa.ccc.p12.

Then, it is imported but it does not display certificate's name.
Even though I imported aaa.bbb.p12 and aaa.ccc.p12 but the command below shows only aaa.bbb twice.

```
# certutil -L -d sql:/etc/ipsec.d/certsdb

Certificate Nickname                                         Trust Attributes
                                                             SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI

aaa.bbb                                                      u,u,u
aaa.bbb                                                      u,u,u
```